# Windows Media Player Embedded in C# Video Speed Change

Tags: c#, video, axwindowsmediaplayer

I currently have a windows media player embedded into my winform on c# and i am now trying to make a button to control the speed of the video play. I currently can use controls to play, pasue and stop, found in ctlcontrols but can't find a way to change the speed of video play through using a button on my form?
An example of my code for pausing the video in it is:
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
But i need some code to change the play speed so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Settings.Rate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564340%28VS.85%29.aspx) is what you are looking for: speed is a double, 1.0 being normal speed.

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate = speed;
```

For [rewinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562650%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```
if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.isAvailable('FastReverse'))
      axWindowsMediaPlayer1.controls.fastReverse();
```

For a full scripting reference check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563945%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks this is super, do you also know how to do it in rewind?

Comment: added fastReverse for you, also make sure to check out the Object Model Reference for Scripting linked above

Comment: axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.rate = speed doesn't works for online URL (buffering).. Please help